Buildozer, gradlew failed, Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0
tried making an app using Buildozer with the help of WSL(ubuntu 22.04.3), on running the buildozer android debug it used gradle == 8.0.2
then i recived this (in short it was expecting gradle == 9.0)

Task :compressDebugAssets FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compressDebugAssets'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
Java heap space
Try:geDebugJniLibFolders
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 1m 32s
22 actionable tasks: 21 executed, 1 up-to-date
STDERR:
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 80):
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

followed by this
ERROR: /mnt/d/cowApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/cowapp/gradlew failed!

below are the changes i did in my buildozer.spec rest everything was set default
should i be changing the android.api from 31 to some older version?
# (str) Title of your application
title = CowApp

# (str) Package name
package.name = cowapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.cowapp

and
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,tflite

and
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,opencv-python,ultralytics

and last
# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 31

